# Force CSS justify creating gap

Tags: html, css

I've been trying all sort of way around to remove the gap under the paragraph or the object where I apply the class, such as giving a negative '`bottom-margin`' and adjusting '`line-height`' but non of them seem to resolve the problem.

[image]

```
.wrapper {  
    width: 940px;
    border: blue solid 1px;
}

p { margin: 0; }

.post-justify { 
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}


.post-justify:after {
    content: '';
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;  
    width: 100%;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PH34N/

Is there a way around in this?

Comment: I just wanted to remove the gap which 'post-justify:after' created.

Comment: you want it to be `display: inline-block` on `:after`? Because that's what's doing it

Comment: Apparently Yes, It needs to use 'inline-block', because the last line needs to be forcibly justified regardless how it looks, and using inline-block results to having a gap. I'm looking for a way to hide or remove that gap.

Comment: Short Answer: No. you can do it.(at least for the time being)

Comment: A fugly way around it that I can think is giving a negative "margin-top" on the next element/paragraph, raising the next element. BUT, it's a really ugly approach, because I have to apply it on every element next to that class. Maybe a jQuery can target those elements but I want to minimize and keep it on a css level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this worked: http://jsfiddle.net/PH34N/9/.

I had to set the `position` to `absolute` and gave it a `top` of `0`, positioning that invisible to it's origin relative to it's container.

```
.post-justify:after {
    content: '';
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;  
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

---

**Revised solution:**

I used adjacent sibling (`.post-justify + p`) to target the next paragraph that uses the class and gave it a negative margin to raise it up.

```
.post-justify { 
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}


.post-justify:after {
    content: '';
    text-align: justify;
    display: inline-block;  
    width: 100%;
} 


.post-justify + p {
     margin-top: -1em;   
}
```

Not the prettiest solution, but, it worked.

Comment: It removes the gap, but unfortunately it also removes the last line justification:(

Comment: That I fail to notice... thanks for pointing it out, @IlyaStreltsyn

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the ugly pseudo-element hack just use [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last). It's been working fine in FF and IE for ages, and also actually works in current Webkit builds (not sure since when, must be less than a year).

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PH34N/2/).

Comment: Thanks, @Niels, but the last line of the paragraph needs to also be justified. In chrome, here's what I get: http://i43.tinypic.com/sf86j4.png and in firefox: http://i43.tinypic.com/4juwkg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The gap can be removed by setting the `line-height` of `.post-justify` to 0 and resetting it to its initial value (or other value used as normal line height for the text, e.g. `1.3`) for the inline child of this element: http://jsfiddle.net/PH34N/5/. But this approach needs one extra element.

```
.post-justify { 
    ...
    line-height: 0;
}

.post-justify > span {
    line-height: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center` for the paragrapgh, and `display:block` for the :after element. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PH34N/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `position: relative` for all the paragraphs, then set i.e. `top: -1em`and then set `top: 0` just for `.post-justify` class. Take a look:

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JhR5r/1/)

Although it isn't very nice solution, it does the job I think.